# Identity up to isomorphism treated as identity in proof

Tags: differential-geometry, banach-spaces, inverse-function-theorem

In the following corollary to the inverse mapping theorem by Serge Lang, Fundamentals of Differential Geometry, 1999, p.17-18, there are two things in the proof which I don't understand, the first step and the last one:

1. If there is an identity up to isomorphism between E and $ F_1 $ as established by $ f'(x_0) $, why can we limit our consideration in the proof to the actual identity? This I have seen several times in proofs, but I don't understand why it can be done here and what the precise circumstances have to be in a proof to allow for this.
2. I dont't see why the local inverse $ \big( \varphi'(0,0) \big)^{-1} $, which is called g at the end of the proof, satisfies the two requirements defined in the corollary for the map g used there.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

Notes: $E, F_1, F_2 $ are Banach spaces. "Morphism" means a $ C^p $-map with $ p \geq 1 $. "Local isomorphism" means a local $ C^p $-isomorphism (dt.: lokaler $ C^p $-Diffeomorphismus). "Toplinear isomorphism" means an isomorphism between topological vector spaces.

Maybe the following drawing is helpful:

[image: Illustration to cor. 5.5]

Comment: $g$ is not $(\varphi'(0,0))^{-1}$, but a local inverse of $\varphi$ at $(0,0)$ - the invertability of $\varphi'(0,0)$  guarantees the existence of such a local inverse. In order to get rid of the identification $E=F_1$ replace $\varphi'(0,0)$ with $\varphi'(x_0, 0)$ and $f'(0)$ with $f'(x_0)$, then the proof will go through (the local inverse should be taken at $(x_0,0)$ then, not $(0,0)$).

Comment: @s.harp, Thanks for your hint. In this case the proof is not worded quite properly, because gramatically "it" refers to the derivative. Nevertheless, I still don't see why we can set $ g := \varphi^{-1} $. And why not $ g := \varphi $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is indeed worded poorly wrt $\varphi'(0,0)$. It is also not necessary to do the identification $E=F_1$; the complication you get from considering them to be different is very manageable. Additionally using the word toplinear is a crime. Let me rewrite the proof with your two questions in mind:

> Define
> $$\varphi: U\times F_2\to F_1\times F_2, \qquad (x,y)\mapsto f(x)+(0,y)$$
> Then the derivative of $\varphi$ at $(x_0,0)$ is equal to $f'(x_0)+(0,\mathrm{id}_{F_2})$. Since $f'(x_0)$ is valued in $F_1$ and is a linear isomorphism you have that $\varphi'(x_0,0)$ is also a linear isomorphism.
>
> By the inverse function theorem it follows that there is a neighbourhood $V\subseteq U\times F_2$ of $(x_0,0)$ so that $\varphi\lvert_V$ is a diffeomorphism (understood to imply $p$-times differentiable). Let $h$ denote the inverse of $\varphi\lvert_V$ and define $g:=(f'(x_0),\mathrm{id}_{F_2})\circ h$. As a composition of diffeomorphisms $g$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $U_1$ be the projection of $V$ onto the $E$ component.
>
> Then for $x\in U_1$:
> $$g(f(x)) = (f'(x_0), \mathrm{id}_{F_2})\left[h(\varphi(x,0))\right]= (f'(x_0),\mathrm{id}_{F_2}) [(x,0)] = (f'(x_0)[x],0)$$
> and $g\circ f$ is valued in $F_1\times\{0\}\subseteq F_1\times F_2$.

Comment: Very nice indeed. Your setting $ g:=(f'(x_0),\mathrm{id}_{F_2})\circ h $ with $ (f'(x_0),\mathrm{id}_{F_2}): U \times F_2 \rightarrow F_1 \times F_2 $ was exactly the missing piece in the puzzle for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one more remark with respect to the original question as expressed in the title of this thread: can we say in a general way that in a proof we can assume an identity where in reality we only have an identity up to isomorphism, if exactly this isomorphism *could* be inserted in this proof at the respective place, the proof remaining valid? Because I think this is what you did.

Comment: Yes. There are two different kinds of proof associated to this idea "up to isomorphism". The first is that usually you are investigating properties (in this case the existence of a map doing a certain thing) that do not care about the particular space in question, only about its isomorphism class wrt a certain structure. In this case you may assume any isomorphism is an identity. The second case is more subtle, sometimes you care about the particular space (for example you want to show something about special elements) but have different canonical or "natural" ways of viewing this space.

Comment: With all your kind help I thought I would be able to work out the scetch of a proof given by Lang for the next corollary 5.7, dual to the one in this thread, and to eliminate his assumptions of identity based on "up to isomorphism" there, too. But I can't and that's frustrating. So I created a follow up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918460/serge-langs-projection).